# Reduce PythonRDD of lists into one list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Going to keep this short post, but happy to add more context / details if they are necessary. I have a PythonRDD that looks as follows:

```
print(myRDD)
PythonRDD[4] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43

print(myRDD.take(1))
[[0.305, 0.302, -0.005, 0.302]]

print(myRDD.collect())
[[0.305, 0.302, -0.005, 0.302], 
 [0.294, 0.183, 0.084, 0.277], 
 [0.184, 0.997, -1.123, 0.654]]
```

Each of the 3 lists contains the 4 values for a 2x2 matrix. I would like to add these 3 matrices together, hence I would like to use some reduce function on myRDD such that the output is:

```
[[.783, 1.482, -1.044, 1.233]]
```

Where .783 = .305 + .294 + .184, etc. I tried to do:

```
myRDD.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

However this did not give me what I desired. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what you need is something along below lines -

```
myRDD.reduce(lambda a, b: [a[0] + b[0], a[1]+b[1],a[2]+b[2],a[3]+b[3]])
```

Comment: I think you need to include within brackets [ ] the following part: `a[0] + b[0], a[1]+b[1],a[2]+b[2],a[3]+b[3]` otherwise you will get `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

```
sc = SparkContext(appName='MyApp')
data = \
    [[0.305, 0.302, -0.005, 0.302],
     [0.294, 0.183, 0.084, 0.277],
     [0.184, 0.997, -1.123, 0.654]]

res = sc.parallelize(data).reduce(lambda x, y: map(sum, zip(x, y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the iteration inside the *reduce()* function, with `lambda function a,b` goes through the lines of your RDD, so:

- First iteration:

**a** is the first line in your RDD

**b** is the second line in your RDD

- Second iteration:

**a** is the result of the operation applied using the lambda function at the previous step

**b** is the third line of your RDD

And so on until the last line.

Therefore, since *line* is a list, if you want to sum the first element of your line with the first element of the following line, you have to do `a[0] + b[0]` , for the sum of the second elements `a[1] + b[1]` and so on.

Solution:

```
>>> finalList = myRDD.reduce(lambda a, b: [a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2], a[3]+b[3]])
[0.7829999999999999, 1.482, -1.044, 1.233]
```

Then, if you need to round the elements of your list, you can use the command **round()** in a list comprehension.

```
>>> myFormattedList = [round(elem,3) for elem in finalList]
>>> myFormattedList
[0.783, 1.482, -1.044, 1.233]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: After @Badacadabra suggestion I have just edited my answer with an additional context